# What permission do I set for a file/folder allow read from PHP but not from browser?

Tags: php, linux, permissions

What permission do I set for a file/folder allow read from PHP but not from browser?

It is a basic users.txt file with username and password.

Comment: I guess chmod `770` or `660` (if u don't want execute)

Comment: I know that this currently seems convenient, but please do not use plain text passwords. Ever. Read about hashing.

Comment: You can't. PHP runs as the same user as the webserver normally (or you're running some suphp / suexec, in which case it's possible). However, the easiest solution is to move the file/folder _outside_ the document root, so PHP can read it, but no direct access is possible.

Comment: Wrikken is right I think... if your script is executing as `nobody` I don't think this will work... you should store users and passwords in database + don't store in plain format, use (at very least) md5.

Comment: outside the web root, or protect with .htacess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put it in the webroot or public_html directory.

So, for example, instead of:

`/var/www/example.com/public_html/secret.file` - // or whatever your server is serving as the domain's root ---

something like:

`/usr/share/php-files/this/path/is/ultimately/arbitrary/secret.txt` -- it doesn't matter where you put the file, as long as you tell php where the file is.

If you want to be extra careful, the permissions should be 600 - if you don't plan to write on it, yourself. And don't forget to `chown` it to whatever your php/webserver user is (typically www-data).

But if it is in the webroot directory, it doesn't matter -- people can get the file and change the permissions afterward. Simply because the user is requesting the file from the webserver, and the webserver has permissions to read it -- the webserver can and will pass the file along as long as it is in a web-accessible directory.

I've seen clients that make this mistake all the time -- leaving horrendous things like 
`full-site.tar.gz` and `all-our-clients'personal-information.sql` --

It isn't hard to keep those things out of the web-root...